# devtools::test() fails: Dependency package X not available

Tags: r, unit-testing, devtools, testthat

Related questions:

- [Dependency package "package_name" not available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33428055/dependency-package-package-name-not-available)
- [How to make devtools::test() consider package dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385475/how-to-make-devtoolstest-consider-package-dependencies)

I have two homemade packages, **A** and **B**. **B** depends on **A** for some functions and has **A** in its `DESCRIPTION` file like this:

`Depends: A`

I have unit tests written using **testthat**. Loading **B** normally works fine, and running the tests manually (running code as a chunk) works fine. However, trying to use automated tests with `devtools::test()` fails with:

```
>devtools::test()
Loading B
Error in (function (dep_name, dep_ver = NA, dep_compare = NA)  : 
  Dependency package A not available.
```

I can't figure out how to begin debugging this as it runs in its own environment etc., so I can't even print anything. I suspect a `.libPaths()` issue, but can't confirm.

I don't know how to minimally reproduce the problem, and I cannot share the code because it is proprietary.

`traceback()` call:

```
> traceback()
6: stop("Dependency package ", dep_name, " not available.")
5: (function (dep_name, dep_ver = NA, dep_compare = NA) 
   {
       if (!requireNamespace(dep_name, quietly = TRUE)) {
           stop("Dependency package ", dep_name, " not available.")
       }
       if (xor(is.na(dep_ver), is.na(dep_compare))) {
           stop("dep_ver and dep_compare must be both NA or both non-NA")
       }
       else if (!is.na(dep_ver) && !is.na(dep_compare)) {
           compare <- match.fun(dep_compare)
           if (!compare(as.numeric_version(getNamespaceVersion(dep_name)), 
               as.numeric_version(dep_ver))) {
               warning("Need ", dep_name, " ", dep_compare, " ", 
                   dep_ver, " but loaded version is ", getNamespaceVersion(dep_name))
           }
       }
       return(TRUE)
   })(dots[[1L]][[5L]], dots[[2L]][[5L]], dots[[3L]][[5L]])
4: mapply(check_dep_version, deps$name, deps$version, deps$compare)
3: load_depends(pkg)
2: load_all(pkg, quiet = TRUE)
1: devtools::test()
```

`sessionInfo()`:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.4.4 (2018-03-15)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Linux Mint 18.2

Matrix products: default
BLAS: /usr/lib/libblas/libblas.so.3.6.0
LAPACK: /usr/lib/lapack/liblapack.so.3.6.0

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C               LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8     LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8   
 [6] LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8    LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                  LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C            
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_0.12.17                          bindr_0.1.1                           xml2_1.2.0                           
 [4] magrittr_1.5                          roxygen2_6.0.1                        devtools_1.13.6                      
 [7] tidyselect_0.2.4                      R6_2.2.2                              rlang_0.2.1                          
[10] stringr_1.3.1                         plyr_1.8.4                            dplyr_0.7.6                          
[13] tools_3.4.4                           B_1.0                                 withr_2.1.2                          
[16] commonmark_1.5                        digest_0.6.15                         assertthat_0.2.0                     
[19] tibble_1.4.2                          bindrcpp_0.2.2                        purrr_0.2.5                          
[22] testthat_2.0.0                        memoise_1.1.0                         glue_1.3.0                           
[25] stringi_1.2.3                         compiler_3.4.4                        pillar_1.2.3                         
[28] pkgconfig_2.0.1
```

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to debug the situation using `debugonce()` on the `devtools::test()` function. This allows interactive debugging of the testing environment.

A call to `installed.packages()` revealed no issues, i.e. packages **A** and **B** were installed in the correct path.

Using `debugonce()`, I traced from `devtools::test()` to `devtools:::load_depends()` to `devtools:::check_dep_version()` to `requireNamespace()` which failed with the following error:

```
Loading required namespace: A
Failed with error:  ‘object 'mutate' not found whilst loading namespace 'A'’
```

So apparently, some kind of hidden namespace error involving a `mutate()` method. Problem is that the `quiet=TRUE` to `requireNamespace()` is on, and not alterable, so the error message does not get to the user, sending them down the wrong path.

Thus the answer turned out to be similar to a previous question [I had answered before](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47104752/3980197), just didn't realize the connection.